# NGINX ignores stop/start/restart signals while reporting no errors

Tags: nginx

These are my NGINX processes:

```
root@ip-192-168-0-12:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ps aux | grep nginx
root      4758  0.0  0.0 102208  2780 ?        Ss   Jul25   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  5585  0.0  0.0 105868  7048 ?        S    Jul26  18:12 nginx: worker process
www-data  5586  0.0  0.0 105868  6972 ?        S    Jul26  18:07 nginx: worker process
www-data  5587  0.0  0.0 102208  2444 ?        S    Jul26   0:07 nginx: cache manager process
root     13190  0.0  0.0  12828  1008 pts/2    S+   20:13   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Now let's stop NGINX:

```
root@ip-192-168-0-12:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx stop
nginx stop/waiting
```

Let's see if the processes still exist (**omg they're still there**):

```
root@ip-192-168-0-12:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ps aux | grep nginx
root      4758  0.0  0.0 102208  2780 ?        Ss   Jul25   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  5585  0.0  0.0 105868  7048 ?        S    Jul26  18:12 nginx: worker process
www-data  5586  0.0  0.0 105868  6972 ?        S    Jul26  18:08 nginx: worker process
www-data  5587  0.0  0.0 102208  2444 ?        S    Jul26   0:07 nginx: cache manager process
root     13230  0.0  0.0  12828  1008 pts/2    S+   20:16   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Then if I run `service nginx start`, the `grep` command would report exactly the same output - one master process, two workers and a cache manager.

What is happening here? Why cannot I just stop NGINX?

Comment: Post the contents of the file /etc/init.d/nginx. This is the script that starts and stops nginx. You can also address the nginx binary directly, use "man nginx" to work out it's options to start / stop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `service nginx stop` sends a SIGTERM to the nginx process, which does not guarantee to stop it.

As suggested in the comment above, in your `/etc/init.d/nginx` can you check the content of the `do_stop()` function and see if you have:

`start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PID --name $NAME`. You may want to change the timeouts there (30, 5 in that example).

Also, check the outcome of the command `nginx -s stop` (fast shutdown) or `nginx -s quit` (graceful shutdown), and see if the processes mentioned above are still running.